# replacing every second occurrence of a letter with a different letter or simbol

Tags: javascript

This pertains to any language that you think will work.    Is there a way to change the look of a text input to replace every second space (space as in when the space bar is hit it makes a space) i need to a way almost like a counter that once it counts 2 spaces then it replaces that 2nd space to a letter or symbol. if someone could help me with this it would be amazing and the purpose is just to change the way the text looks in this way functionality does not matter as long as it reads like normal text. ( if it helps it would be every odd number of spaces gets changed.)

for example i want to be able to copy and paste something in like this> "i went down to the sea to pick up many sticks for my collection"

and have it return something like this

i%went down%to the%sea to%pick up%many sticks%for my%collection

the end goal is for the symbol to be a different color so it stands out from the text so if that would be possible that would be amazing.

Comment: What have you attempted to do yourself?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: i have written the place to copy and paste the text that returns what ever input given but it seems like there is not a very simple way to edit specifications into text at least from the resources i know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose javascript, but there are multiple languages that you could choose and there are multiple ways to accomplish this.  This is the train of thought that you should use when solving this problem:

1. Determine the characters that you want to replace
2. Determine the character that you want to replace it with
3. Since we don't want to replace every single one, what is the pattern/frequency that you want to replace found occurrences with.

For the 3rd question, you've said that you want to replace every other occurrence, so we need to keep track of the count of occurrences. And replace it when `occurrence modulo 2 = 1`.  This says replace every odd occurrence.

I chose to use regex to find all the spaces in the sentence, have a counter `n` and increment the counter every time I find a space.

This leaves us with the following code:

```
const input =  "i went down to the sea to pick up many sticks for my collection";

let n = 0;
const output = input.replace(/\s/g, (m, i, og) => {
  return (n++ % 2) ? m : '%';
});

// output = "i%went down%to the%sea to%pick up%many sticks%for my%collection"
```

Also please take a look at [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) so you can learn about using regex, and to learn about what the function does.  This will help you learn and solve similar problems by yourself in the future.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it is crazy awesome how fast you guys responded!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a boolean variable to count odd and even spaces and string.prototyoe.replace with a callback function:

```
var str = 'i went down to the sea to pick up many sticks for my collection';
var odd = true;
str = str.replace(/\s/gi, (spaceChar)=>{
  odd = !odd;
  return !odd ? spaceChar : '%'; // this is what you wrote (every second)
  // return odd ? spaceChar : '%'; // this is what your expected result shows (every second starting with the first occurence)
});
```

Comment: @t-engineer If you have any further questions, feel free to ask. If your question is answered please select an answer :)

Comment: so i have a question or two

Comment: how do i set the string that i want returned with the % marks as something that is an changeable input by the user like i would like the user to be able to copy and paste what every they want and have the %'s be added in at that point

Comment: @t-engineer just add a form to your document with an input or textarea field. Then you can use the value of one of these elements as string for the above code.